# Force trailing slash in .htaccess - http and https pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I want to force trailing slashes on a Magento site. Under normal circumstances the code below works fine. However, this site has some https pages such as the login and checkout pages. I'm wondering how I account for this in the htaccess file? I'm assuming I need to set up a separate rule for these https pages?

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to force a trailing slash for both `HTTPs` and `http`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @thickguru. Seems fairly obvious now. Should `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` also be included to avoid files with extensions?

Comment: Yes sorry, I should have included that. I just assumed. Which I should never do :P

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll test this and hopefully will sort the issue.

Comment: Awesome, please do let me know if you have any issues. But this should  work without any problems.